# Current communication delay to mars

Tags: mars, communication

I read that the communication delay between earth and mars is [between 3 and 21 minutes](http://www.spaceacademy.net.au/spacelink/commdly.htm).

So the delay changes over time (since the distance between earth and mars changes over time).

How can I get the delay at the *current* moment, or another specified moment in time?

Comment: See http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/present-distances-between-planet-how-can-i-find-them

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+to+mars+in+light+seconds

Comment: @JamesKilfiger For the uninitiated this deserves more than a link to Wolfram Alpha and a question about finding the distance between two planets.

Answer (score 7):

Download the [Nasa's Eyes](https://eyes.nasa.gov/) program, and use the "measure distance" option (rightclick on an object), to find its distance to another object. The distance in light seconds/minutes is the signal travel time.

The advantage over WolframAlpha is that you can easily set the time and check the distance for any arbitrary date; W.A. takes some tricky work to force it to give anything else than 'now'.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer! Is there a way to get this value programmatically, by an api/module/plugin (preferably Python)?

Comment: @Kevin [SPICE](http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/) is the set of APIs that powers NASA's Eyes.